# Skipped frames even after offloading work to new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I'm making an app that automatically takes a picture once the user unlocks their phone.  I have a service running that supports a broadcast receiver which responds to successful phone entry. I'm having problems with the actual picture taking and saving onto external storage.  It's skipping frames and either storing the image minutes after a pic is taken or not at all.  I've offloaded the picture-taking to AsyncTask as well as starting a new Thread via Runnable.  Nothing, please assist.

```
public class MasterService extends Service {

private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        private Camera camera;
        private SurfaceView preview;
        private SurfaceHolder holder;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                //code for other versions
            }
            else {
                preview = new SurfaceView(context);
                holder = preview.getHolder();
                holder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);

                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1000, 1000, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0, PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

                wm.addView(preview, lParams);
            }
        }

        SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();

                for (int i=0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

                    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                        camera = Camera.open(i);
                    }
                }

            }

            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                try
                {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {

                }

                Camera.Parameters cParams = camera.getParameters();

                cParams.setJpegQuality(100);
                camera.setParameters(cParams);

                camera.startPreview();

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                                File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg");

                                if (photo.exists()) {
                                    photo.delete();
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

                                    fos.write(data);
                                    fos.close();
                                }
                                catch (java.io.IOException e)
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                thread.start();
            }

            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            }
        };


    };
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT));

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

}

Comment: why are you using a sticky service. it costs a lot. Don't use until you need it.

Comment: I need it to keep the Broadcast Receiver alive to wait for someone to login.